# How to see if a string matches an item in combobox list

Tags: vba, excel

Below is my code that compares the given textToSearch with items in a combobox, If its not there then it prompt the user about it, otherwise it select it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub comboBoxCheck(listMy As ComboBox, textToSearch As String, msgBoxText As String)
Dim i As Integer
If textToSearch = "" Then textToSearch = "NA" 'Empty string is equilaent to NOT AVAILABLE in my case
textToSearch = UCase(textToSearch)
For i = 0 To listMy.ListCount - 1
    If listMy.List(i) = textToSearch Then
        listMy.ListIndex = i
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
'could add the text but In this case prompt the user what the text was, typically spelling mistake etc..
MsgBox ("You have some invalid entry for " & msgBoxText & "which has the value: " & textToSearch & "Please select correct value in the combobox and then press OK!")
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a question or are you just showing us your code?

Comment: Just showing my code, in case someone else needs it. Couldn't find any good examples on stackoverflow so I thought I should post it here. Posted the question with the answer to it. Feel free to improve it or edit it @arcadeprecinct